# Rails Error - params not passing user id from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm building an Events app and I'm trying to create a link from the Event show page to the event creator's profile but I'm getting the following error -

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show
Couldn't find User with 'id'=21

The error highlights this particular line of code in the Users Controller -

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

end
```

The development log produces this output -

Started GET "/users/21" for ::1 at 2016-04-15 12:37:08 +0100
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"21"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 8]]
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 21]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 14ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User with 'id'=21):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:14:in `show'

The user id (in this instance 5) is not being passed.I've tried numerous arguments in the show.html.erb page but none will work. Changing the show argument in the users controller to @user = current_user only succeeds in bringing up the profile of the user viewing the event and not the profile of the event creator.

Here's my code -

Events Controller

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_event, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy,]
# the before_actions will take care of finding the correct event for us
# this ties in with the private method below
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
# this ensures only users who are signed in can alter an event

def index
    if params[:category].blank?
        @events = Event.all.order("created_at DESC")
    else
        @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id
        @events = Event.where(category_id: @category_id).order("created_at DESC")
    end
    # The above code = If there's no category found then all the events are listed
    # If there is then it will show the EVENTS under each category only
end

def show
end

def new
    @event = current_user.events.build
    # this now builds out from a user once devise gem is added
    # after initially having an argument of Event.new
    # this assigns events to users
end
# both update and create actions below use event_params as their argument with    an if/else statement 
def create
    @event = current_user.events.build(event_params)
    # as above this now assigns events to users
    # rather than Event.new

    if @event.save
        redirect_to @event, notice: "Congratulations, you have successfully created a new event."
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def edit
    # edit form
    # @edit = Edit.find(params[:id])
    @event = current_user.events.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    if @event.update(event_params)
        redirect_to @event, notice: "Event was successfully updated!"
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    @event.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
end

private

def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:title, :location, :date, :time, :description, :number_of_spaces, :is_free, :price, :organised_by, :organiser_profile, :url, :image, :category_id)
    # category_id added at the end to ensure this is assigned to each new event created
end

def find_event
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
end
```

end

Users Controller -

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!


def new
    @user = User.new
end


def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

end

def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

        if @user.save
            flash[:success] = "Welcome to Mama Knows Best"
            session[:uid] = @user.id
            redirect_to root_path
        else
            render 'new'
        end
end

def edit  
    @user =  current_user                             
end  

def update
    @user = current_user
        if @user.update(user_params)
            flash[:success] = "Profile successfully updated!"
            redirect_to root_path
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
end


private

def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :username, :biography, :email, :url)

end 


end
```

Show page -

```
<%= image_tag @event.image.url %>

<h1><%= @event.title %></h1>
<p>Location </p>
<p><%= @event.location %></p>
<p>Date</p>
<p><%= @event.date.strftime('%A, %d %b %Y') %></p>
<p>Time</p>
<p><%= @event.time.strftime('%l:%M %p') %></p>
<!-- above expresses date and time as per UK expectations -->
<p>More details</p>
<p><%= @event.description %></p>
<p>Number of Spaces available</p>
<p><%= @event.number_of_spaces %></p>
<% if @event.is_free? %>
<p>This is a free event</p>
<% else %>
<p>Cost per person</p>
<p><%= @event.price %></p>
<% end %>
<p>Organiser</p>
<p><%= @event.organised_by %></p>
<p>Organiser Profile</p>
<button><%= link_to "Profile", user_path %></button>
<p>Link to Organiser site</p>
<button><%= link_to "Organiser site", @event.url %></button>

<p>Submitted by</p> 
<p><%= @event.user.name %></p>


<% if user_signed_in? and current_user == @event.user %>
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_event_path %>
<%= link_to "Delete", event_path, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you   sure?"} %>
<%= link_to "Back", root_path %>
<% else %>
<%= link_to "Back", root_path %>
<%= link_to "Book the Event", new_event_booking_path(@event) %>
<% end %>
```

routes -

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


  devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }  



  resources :users
  resources :events do

    resources :bookings
  end
  # get 'welcome/index'


  authenticated :user do
    root 'events#index', as: "authenticated_root"
  end


    root 'welcome#index'

  # the above method comes from devise and allows for the site to have a home page
  # for users not signed in and one for when they are signed in


end
```

I haven't added anything relating to the users profile on the form partial as I didn't believe it to be relevant. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is an `Event` connected to `User` with any association?

Comment: `<button><%= link_to "Profile", user_path %></button> ` user_path` is helper which resolves to `UserController#show`  and expects an argument. Do `user_path(current_user)`

Comment: I've tried current_user and it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, User has_many Events and Events belongs_to User

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reiterate your question, you want a link on the event page that goes to the event organiser's profile page?

```
<p>Organiser Profile</p>
<button><%= link_to "Profile", user_path(@event.user) %></button>
```

Comment: Cheers - that fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

`user_path` is a path helper in Rails which resolves to RESTful route of `/users/:id`. This goes in `UserController#show` and expects `params` hash to contain `:id`.

For your case, you are missing the argument. You need to do:

```
<button><%= link_to "Profile", user_path(current_user) %></button>
```

It automatically picks up id and passes it to params hash as : `{:id => 7}`
[Doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

You may also want fix other such helpers call:

`event_path`
`edit_event_path` with appropriate argument.

Comment: Try `user_path(@event.user)` just to check if it's route issue or current_user's

Comment: No its not that either.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using for user authentication, devise or similar gem? Did you build your own? If so do you have current_user defined in the sessions helper? The below code is how current_user could be defined (a la Hartl Rails tutorial). This will allow you to use current_user in views and controllers.

```
def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user && user.authenticated?(:remember, cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end
```

I also noticed in your Users Controller under def create. I believe it should be session[:id] instead of session[:uid]. Please excuse me if this is not the case. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using devise but I've built it out a bit for the purpose of creating user profiles. This is my routes file -

Comment: Sorry - I've added routes above.

Comment: what is the output when you run $ bundle exec rake routes? I have a similar layout with users and events and the <%= link_to "profile", user_path(current_user) %> worked fine on my event page. Another thing to check, is your events db table recording the proper user id when the event is created?

Comment: How do I check that because I think that might be something to do with it. The error message is stating the event id number not the user id.

Comment: what kind of db are you using for development? if you are using SQLite, DB Browser for SQLite works well (download here: http://sqlitebrowser.org/). Download your db/development.sqlite3 file and view it in the db browser. You can also view all entries in your rails console by searching >> Event.all

Comment: I think its purely expecting an argument with user_path but can't figure out which it should be.

Comment: The issue is that the event_id=21 and its trying to find user_id=21 which is incorrect.

Comment: The correct method is definitely user_path(current_user), but that path only works if current_user is defined in the session. Perhaps fixing the typo in session[:uid] to session[:id] in the users controller will help that. // Is the events table logging the correct user_id? //  Also, I believe " submitted by <%= (at)event.user.name %> " should be <%= (at)event.users.name %>

Comment: How do I check the events table? I think this is key because it appears to be checking for an id before completing the action and the id being thrown back is the event id not the user id.

Comment: did you see my comment above? You can either use a db browser like DB Browser for SQLite or type >> Event.all in your rails console.

Comment: I've looked in the console and the correct user id is being logged. The event id is being logged before the user id.

Comment: Try <%= link_to "Profile", @event.user %>